# Why does a routing rule directing to a local network interface accept more than one destination IP addreses?

Tags: routing, route

```
$ /sbin/route -n 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.122.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens3
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens3

$ /sbin/ifconfig
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.202  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe99:5eee  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:54:00:99:5e:ee  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14906  bytes 18020195 (17.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7390  bytes 786783 (768.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 35568

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 496  bytes 39840 (38.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 496  bytes 39840 (38.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

When a packet arrives the host and the packet is destined for a private IP address (192.168.122.2),

- is the packet delivered to ens3 (192.168.122.202) as the final destination, according to the second entry in the routing table?
- if yes, isn't that wrong, because the intended destination 192.168.122.2 isn't in the local host? In other words, why does the second entry direct packets with  destination IP addresses varying in **a range** to a local network interface with **just one** IP address?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re forgetting that the interface provides access to a *network*, which (if it’s an IP network) is defined by a base IP address and a netmask (or prefix length in IPv6).

```
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens3
```

says that packets addressed to the 192.168.122/24 network are to be sent to `ens3`, the interface to the network (and then the packet will be sent to the appropriate host, but that’s not this system’s concern).

A network is supposed to provide equal access to all hosts on the network, so `ens3` allows packets to be sent to any host in the 192.168.122/24 network, effectively in a peer-to-peer fashion, without the help of any gateway or router.

```
0.0.0.0         192.168.122.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens3
```

says that packets which the kernel doesn’t know what to do with should be sent to 192.168.122.1, the gateway, which will forward it appropriately (if it can). The gateway is accessible *via* `ens3`.

Neither of these guarantee that any given packet will actually reach its destination; that’s why the network (or even the interface) can report errors such as “destination host unreachable”.

(Sticklers might complain that I’m ignoring L2/L3 issues, but they’re not relevant here and would only end up being confusing.)

Comment: Thanks. (1) Do you mean that first line in the table forwards a packet **to the gateway of a network**, while the second line forwards a packet **to a local network interface**? (2)  Although it is not the concern of the second line,  how is a packet further  be sent from the local network interface **to the appropriate host**? Is it sent **to the gateway or router of the network** first and let the gateway or router decide which host to send the packet to? (3) Both lines in the routing table have `ens3` as network interface, and do they use the network interface in the same way?

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) The current host can communicate directly with other hosts on the network(s) it’s directly connected to, there’s no need for a gateway. (3) Pretty much.